# How to add an expiry time for cached Angular2 http response using rxjs observables

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I am using rxjs `publishReplay(1)` and `refCount` to cache http response. What's the best way to put an expiry time for the caching. I am getting a token using http call which expires every 1 hour.

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService{
public url: string;
private token:Observable<any> = null;

constructor(private _http:Http){

}

getSecurityToken(url:string): any {

    headers.append("securitycode","*******");

    if(!this.token){
        this.token = this._http.post(url,{headers:headers})
            .map(this.extractData)
            .publishReplay(1)
            .refCount()
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    return this.token;
}     


private extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log(res.status);
    if(res.status == 204) { 
        return [];
    }
    else{
        let body = res.json();
        return body;
    }
}

private handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
   console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
   return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `publishReplay` internally uses the `ReplaySubject` that takes as the second argument the time window which defines how long is each cached item valid.

So in your case it could be for example:

```
...
.publishReplay(1, 60 * 1000)
```

See: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-publishReplay

Comment: Thanks @martin. I have tried using `publishReplay(1, 60 * 1000)` . I am making this rest call on a page load. When i load it for the first time i am getting the response but when i got back and come to the page it's not giving any data. The page is blank. Do i have to add `.map(this.extractData)` after the `refCount()`

Comment: I have no idea because I have no idea what your application does. Can you make a plnkr or jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Not gonna work if all the subscribers unsubscribe. The buffer will get cleared.

Comment: @moonstom how to make automatic subscription (well, data retrieval) after cache is expired? Seems like it should not be needed in my case - I am using it with async pipe on the page - nevertheless i have 'empy cells' problem (obviously, after cache is expired) when using second parameter

Comment: I found this answer with google, but had the same problem. A better answer can be found here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947878/temporarily-caching-http-responses-from-parametrised-requests-using-rxjs-and-an/54957061#54957061
The take(1) at the end of the request is really important!

Answer (score -1):

Just in case, somebody else runs into this question: A better solution can be found here: [Temporarily caching HTTP responses from parametrised requests using RxJS (and Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947878/temporarily-caching-http-responses-from-parametrised-requests-using-rxjs-and-an/54957061#54957061)

I had the same problem and asked this questions: [rxjs publishReplay with windowTime parameter reseting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221252/rxjs-publishreplay-with-windowtime-parameter-reseting/67221958#67221958)

Voted to close this question, but added the new links just in case somebody else finds this solution and spends 4 hours debugging it, just like me