# rxjs publishReplay with windowTime parameter reseting

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to limit the time subscriptions are cached in rxjs. Previously the caching was done with    `pipe(publishReplay(1), refCount())`. After finding this nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123110/how-to-add-an-expiry-time-for-cached-angular2-http-response-using-rxjs-observabl/43123185#43123185) and reading the [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-publishReplay), I found out that this cache time can be limited by passing a second parameter to `publishReplay`.
Example: `publishReplay(1, 60 * 1000)`

I tried to make a minimal example:

```
<button (click)="test()">Test</button>
```

JS:

```
  urlofApi = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=helloWorld";

  testX = this.http.get(this.urlofApi).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log("called")),
    publishReplay(1, 5),
    refCount()
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  test() {
    const x = this.testX.subscribe();
  }
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z7ecyn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

However the reslt is not discareded after 5ms, but held indefinitly. What am I missing?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 Hours of debugging, I found the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54957061

All I had to do, was add a `take(1)` at the end.

New example:

```
  testX = this.http.get(this.urlofApi).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log("called")),
    publishReplay(1, 5),
    refCount(),
    take(1)
  );
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tyrbdw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Full example:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import { publishReplay, refCount, take, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  urlofApi = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=helloWorld";

  testX = this.http.get(this.urlofApi).pipe(
    tap(() =>
      console.log(
        `++ api was newly called at ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} ++`
      )
    ),
    publishReplay(1, 5000),
    refCount(),
    take(1)
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  test() {
    console.log("Requesting data from API");
    this.testX.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => console.log("completed"));
  }
}
```